# System menu disappeared after upgrade

Tags: 11.04, gnome-panel, system

Hello 
After upgrade to Ubuntu 11 system menu on desktop has been disappeared. What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: have you tried choosing the Ubuntu Classic session at the log-in screen?

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by system menu? are you using unity or ubuntu classic? ,,,if you are using unity it does not have a drop down menu's like gnome2.x but you can still use the older desktop. log out and at the bottom were it say's session pick ubuntu classic.

Comment: He is likely using classic and no, you can't use the older desktop, you can only use a replica that looks similar and lacks things suchs as the system menu (was Application, Places, System, now it's only Application and Places)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for system settings you can find it where you log out (panel right hand side):

[image: Gear icon]

at the bottom it says <kbd>system settings</kbd>. It has almost all options you can change. Also install (if you did not do that yet) `CCSM` (CompizConfig Settings Manager) for some settings regarding Unity itself.

If you need something else you need to open the 'application' launcher and start typing the 1st few letters of  what you are looking for.